# Tomcat blocking when handle huge HTTPS connections

Tags: java, tomcat, file-upload, https

We use HTTPS to do file upload from client to tomcat web server, sometimes we will met the tomcat blocking issue, but don't know why this happens, in normal case, file can be uploaded successfully.

When tomcat is blocking, all the https connections can't be created, after about 5 minutes, some https connections will be released.

Not sure what trigger the tomcat go blocking, and how to avoid this, helps!!!Thanks!

Comment: Does your system architecture involve HTTP virtual hosting and/or a virtualization platform?

Comment: we use vmware, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

change **maxThreads** value to hit count on **server.xml** file and check

```
<Connector port="****" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           />
```

Comment: The maxThreads value has set to 300, in face, this issue is not always happened, it just happened in sometime.

<Connector port="${https.port}" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="300" scheme="https" secure="true"
               keystoreFile="webapps/hm/.keystore"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystorePass="${keystorepass}"/>